# How to plot a grouped bar graph in R with different data structures

Tags: r, data-structures, graphing

Say I have the following data structures-

```
c <- c(1,2)
d <- c(3,5)
e <- c(5,6)
f <- c(4,4)
```

How do I make a grouped bar graph such that the contents of each data structure are the bars that are side by side. For example, the first label on the x axis would be C and it would have the bars of 1 and 2 on it, D would be the next with the bars of 3 and 5 on it, and so on.

Any tips/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
c <- c(1,2)
d <- c(3,5)
e <- c(5,6)
f <- c(4,4)

dat <- cbind(c,d,e,f)
barplot(dat,beside=TRUE)
```

This is pretty introductory stuff in R - I suggest you take a read of a few tutorial websites before asking too many basic queries on stackoverflow. E.g.:

http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/#barcharts

http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/qualitative-data/bar-graph

[image]

Comment: oh my goshh thank you so much. Last question, if you don't mind: What does cbind exactly do?

Comment: @sadfrogger - just try it in R `cbind(c,d,e,f)` and hit enter. It `c`olumn `bind`s vectors like your `c`,`d` etc together. You can get help on functions in R by typing `?functionname` like `?cbind`